# How to hide and show sections in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a quiz game with 4 questions and a result page using jQuery with multiple answer that apply to a question with score and number of correct answers attempted. Each section is shown based on the click event
For testing I added the dummy code in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Johnny_blake/7c2965oe/3/

The issue is that the sections are not shown or hidden properly while clicking on next and user experience is really bad, for reference I followed this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/DUNK9/2/

I added the sections to be hidden on start of the quiz:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".questionOne").hide();
$(".questionTwo").hide();
 $(".questionThree").hide();
 $(".questionFour").hide();
$(".questionOne_correct").hide();
$(".questionTwo_correct").hide();
 $(".questionThree_correct").hide();
$(".questionFour_correct").hide();
 $(".questionOne_incorrect").hide();
$(".questionTwo_incorrect").hide();
$(".questionThree_incorrect").hide();
$(".questionFour_incorrect").hide();
});
```

Problems noticed:

1. The above classes do not properly show or hide in the sections, for
   instance, when the answer is correct, on click of the button
   (g4next) works fine, but incorrect answer with button (g4next) does
   not move to the next section.
2. The input is not hidden as I'm making the image act as the checkbox, on click with ::after a tick is added but it is not working.

   Things to be added:
3. How can I add the score with percentage i.e., 25% for each
   questions and number of correct answers in text.
4. A progress step bar on each question section.

How can I make this to work as a dynamic quiz?

Comment: First of all use more generic `css` 

    `.question{
      /*style for all questions*/
    }
    .incorrect{
      /*additional style for all incorrect questions*/
    }
    .question:not(incorrect){
      /*style for all correct questions*/
    }
    .question:nth-child(n){
     /*style specific nth question*/
    }`

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided doesn't work at all for me. You should look for some already made solution/template online, like this one: https://dev.to/sulaimonolaniran/building-a-simple-quiz-with-html-css-and-javascript-4elp